# How can a game have both Full and Partial Controller suport?

Tags: steam, controllers

When looking at the game [Scourge: Outbreak](http://store.steampowered.com/app/227560/) I noticed that it features both "Partial Controller Support" and "Full controller support".

[image: Both Controller]

At first I thought maybe if a game has full support, it must also have partial.  [Goat Simulator](http://store.steampowered.com/app/265930/), however, only has full support.  Looking through to see if I could find another game with both, I found [Mercenary Kings](http://store.steampowered.com/app/218820/) also features Partial and Full support.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was a mistake when creating those tags.

Comment: @Assylum Any way to figure out which it actually is?

Comment: Not without asking on the forums.

Comment: it could possibly depend on what part of the game you are playing.

Comment: @Dupree3 See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94987/whats-the-difference-between-full-controller-support-and-partial-controller).  If a controller does not work for part of the game, that seems to indicate a "Partial Controller Support" entry.

Comment: Then your question has an obvious answer. Its a glitch, report it case closed. Sorry for input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that having both is an error in the entry at some point.  According to the developer of Scourge:

> "The game is fully suported, even the text input in Big Picture mode" [...] "Seams like an error." [source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/227560/discussions/1/558752356877301376/)

After looking through many of the Full controller support and Partial controller support games, it seems like this is a rare case.  It is likely that any game that lists both did so by accident.

Answer (score 2):

It can't, they are mutually exclusive. Whoever was entering the information made a mistake. You can ask on the game's forums whether it has full support.

Comment: I always thought it meant you could bind all the controls to the controller but controlls could also be bound to the keyboard.

Comment: @Nicholas_Moughler full controller support means you don't need a keyboard or mouse to play the game at all, it doesn't mean you can't use k+m to play it.

Comment: Actually, I thought one was for big picture mode while the other was not.